# Setting the event for first form when the second form is closed that is opened by first form in Windows form

Tags: c#, .net, forms

I am developing a .NET windows form application. I am absolute beginner to .NET Windows form, I am an asp.net developer. I am having a problem with setting events to forms.

Inside the form1, I open the form2 like this in a click event

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
form2.show();
```

Inside the form2, there is a button and when the button is clicked, I will close the form2 and the fire an event in form1 that opened form2. How can I bind event between that 2 forms? How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the FormClosed event on the Form class.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.formclosed(v=vs.110).aspx

```cs
form2.FormClosed += Form2_FormClosed;

private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{

}
```